# Elementary os on login <ERROR> failed to enable link training

Tags: linux, drivers, intel, intel-graphics

When logging in the system knocks an error:

[drm: intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] failed to enable link training

Maybe it happened because of whom I installed nvidia-smi. No video card, Intel-i7 processor.

[image]